# How to tell when page finished loading (server side, not javascript)

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I am trying to run a headless version of Google Chrome on an Ubuntu 16.04 instance, but it's very important for me to know if the page did finish loading completely before starting different scripts that are dependent on Chrome.

I've tried

```
google-chrome --kiosk --enable-logging --v=1 --log-net-log=/tmp/chrome-net.log --video-threads=6 --no-sandbox --no-experiments --no-default-browser-check --no-pings --no-service-autorun --no-wifi --noerrdialogs --process-per-tab --disable-gpu --no-first-run --disable-java --disable-plugins --disable-translate --disk-cache-size=$((1024 * 1024)) --disk-cache-dir=/tmp/chrome/ --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome/ --incognito --force-device-scale-factor=1 --window-size=1280,720--window-position=0,0 URL
```

chrome-net.log does not tell me much, same for the debug log (or i'm not sure what exactly to search for)

Is there any other way to find when the page is fully loaded (or at least DOMContentLoaded equivalent)?

Thanks

Comment: Fully loaded means even the scripts, images and other types resources loaded?

Comment: If possible, yes - if not at least the DOMContentLoaded alternative will be useful as well.

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaScript code that is alternative to DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: No, something in the server CLI or logs from Chrome

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to generate a HAR file or something like that from the chrome net log which has a weird format

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I assume you would like to generate a HAR (HTTP Archive) file from Chrome for logging purpose, here are the steps you might want to do to generate HAR file:

1. Press `F12` key to pull up `Developer tools`.
2. Click on the `Network` Tab.
3. Here in the tab, there is a `Preserve log` option which you need to select it. Check out [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFuNP.png) screenshot.
4. Once it is selected, reload your current page. There is a **red** button like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eWGt.png) one. The red button means that the browser recording its activity on the current page. Sometimes, you might see a **black** button which means the browser is not recording its activity. But you can simply click on it to start recording and again reload the page.
5. While the red button is `ON`, right click on anywhere in the `Network` tab like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3uRn.png) one and then click `Save as HAR with Content`. You will then be asked to save the file and you're done.

The HAR file you generated is available in JSON format. You can use JSON tools to view or edit the data. [JSON Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-editor/lhkmoheomjbkfloacpgllgjcamhihfaj) is a popular JSON chrome extension for viewing and editing JSON data.

Hope it helps you achieve what you're looking for!

Comment: hey @Perumal93 that is all cool - but i'm talking about CLI stuff here. There's no desktop involved. and all has to happen in the background.

Comment: You mean like an automated job?

Comment: Does not to be a "job", i want to, let's say 5s after chrome was launched from CLI with the kiosk mode on a server, to get the HAR or something similar where i can check all the requests that have been made. Remember, this is all server side. No VNC, no mouse or keyboard :)

Comment: The command you provided in the question generates you log file. Do you want it in the format like HAR?

Comment: It does, but that log is very very hard to read/analyze. I was thinking if it's possible to make convert that to a HAR or generate a HAR by default not that log. Also tried to search for some tools that will make the reading easier out of that log, but there not too many. Guess i need to find their documentation and try to parse that somehow and see if things make sense. I was just trying to get a shortcut to get a HAR so i can actually be able to script: if request X failed, do this.

Comment: Use `JSON Editor` for chrome extension to read those log files. Here is the link. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-editor/lhkmoheomjbkfloacpgllgjcamhihfaj. But these files are heavy to read. You need some patience to wait until it's all loaded into your `JSON Editor`. If you have high end performance PC, you need not to worry about them all being loaded into the editor since it will be processed fast on these PC's.

Comment: we're in a docker container inside a server ;) but i'll try to see the extension, and i'll check if there's any other way to read from an extension the network logs.

Comment: You could download the log file from `/tmp/chrome-net.log` and load it into `JSON Editor`?

Comment: That will not really work, because of 2 things: 1) that log, when tailing it live, it's malformed. 2) has a good 2-3sec delay, but still the end of that log is malformed . Which is why i was trying to find alternatives